# Split CSV files through awk, with separator used within a string

Tags: string, bash, csv, awk, separator

I've got a CSV file that I need to split, to extract the `i`th column value of each record.

Here is a sample `file.csv`.

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
"value1_1_a, value1_1_b",value1_2,value1_3
"value2_1_a, value2_1_b, value2_1_c",value2_2,value2_3
```

In general, if I'd like to extract (for instance) `Column2` values, I'd opt for a command like:

```
cat file.csv | awk -F, '{print $2}'
```

to get a result like:

```
Column2
value1_2
value2_2
```

Nevertheless, since `Column1` values include strings with a variable number of `,` separator, I get wrong data. Hence, how can I use `awk` to accomplish my purpose?

Comment: If only column one ever has the problem of embedded delimiters, and all records have the same number of fields, it may be easier to work backwards from `NF` than to deal with `FPAT`. E.g. `{ print $(NF - 1) }`

Comment: Thanks @jas, it theoretically work, but the column containing the string may also be in the middle of the columns list.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have to use `awk`, you could use `csvtool` to do the job for you, which allows referring to the name or the number of the column - http://colin.maudry.com/csvtool-manual-page/

`csvtool namedcol Column2 csvfile`

```
Column2
value1_2
value2_2
```

`csvtool col 2 csvfile`

```
Column2
value1_2
value2_2
```

Or you can use an `awk` field pattern instead of a field-separator pattern:

`cat csvfile | awk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '{print $2}`

```
Column2
value1_2
value2_2
```

Comment: Thanks. Any way to make it through `awk` only, or other standard tools like `sed`?

Comment: Check update for GNU Awk 4 extension example.

Comment: Where is it possible to download `csvtool` outside of `apt`? Useful for instance for non-Linux systems.

Comment: For which system? You could also use csvkit using pip which can be installed on windows with python - https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: For macOS. For now, I've solved by removing the string column content, with the following command: `cat file.csv | sed 's/\".*\"/removed\_text/'`. Although this works in my specific case, it is not a good and general solution.

Comment: `csvkit` is available on homebrew - https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/csvkit